# Dynamic cast to generic type in Java

Tags: java

Here is a trivial example I have put together:

```
private static <T> T getValue(T defaultValue) {
    if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) {
        return (T) true;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Essentially, I wish to return "true" if T is of boolean type. However, I get a compile error that boolean cannot be cast to T.

How do I do it?

Also, is there a way to check if T is of type boolean? Regards.

Comment: Can you `return (T) Boolean.TRUE` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
        return (T) true;
```

To

```
        return (T) Boolean.TRUE;
```

This will work as  Boolean.True is an instance of class Boolean.   The value "true" is of the primitive type boolean.

Answer (score 5):

true is a primitive type and you want to return an Object. You should wrap true in an object.

This works:

```
private static <T> T getValue(T defaultValue) {
    if (defaultValue instanceof Boolean) {
        return (T)Boolean.valueOf(true);
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Is it because the native booleans are not autoboxed to it's wrapper classes?

Comment: Good question. Boolean is autoboxed as other primitive types. The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that it should do autoboxing. Look here to see which conversions are boxed: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html