# Cast to generic type (T) is never checked by the compiler?

Tags: java, generics, casting

```
static <T> void f1(Base arg1, T arg2) {
    T loc = (T) arg1; // why Derived is "kind of cast" to String?
    System.out.println(loc.getClass().getName()); // would print: Derived
}

f1(new Derived(), "sdf");  // T is String - inferred from arg2

class Base { }

class Derived extends Base { }
```

Am I correct in my thoughts: **writing cast (T) means "compiler cannot and is not going to check this cast anyway"**. **At compile-time the compiler does not know what arg2 would be (and it could be anything), so compiler cannot rule out that the cast could work and has to trust the programmer**. Thus this cast is just never checked at compile time. **In runtime local var declaration looks like `Object loc = arg1;` (after type erasure).** So everything works fine just because compiler never cares about this (T) cast?

P.S: My research: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767212/casting-to-generic-type-in-java-doesnt-raise-classcastexception), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960987/generic-type-cast). [This is also very interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28242231/dynamic-cast-to-generic-type-in-java) ("casting primitive to generic": (T) true) My question is more clearly pinpointed on the problem, the question is also about whether the cast (T) checked by the compiler and there are no distractions in the code sample in question.

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you are asking here: what are you saying the compiler does when given this code? Does it compile or not?

Comment: explicit cast is always trusted. and surely programmers very often betray such trust.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right. it's not 100% of the time. I am more thinking of the situations where generics is involved.

Comment: attempting to answer it, it's beyond compiler's capability to check the cast on spot. however, jvm will check the type eventually, when you attempt the call something type specific. is it what you want to know?

Comment: Is there more context to this question? Why would you write a method that effectively takes method(Base, Object) and expect the compiler to check the casting:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: You should get a warning on that cast, and that code might break in Java 13, Also the code is lying, is it not? `arg2.getClass().cast(arg1)`?

Comment: @JoopEggen Do you just mean it might break in the future, or is there some reason to think it’ll break in Java 13 specifically?

Comment: In the future, type erasing goes but so far. Run time types will come; for instance there is effort for `List<int>` so the language is still not stonified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At compile-time the compiler does not know what arg2 would be (and it could be anything), so compiler cannot rule out that the cast could work and has to trust the programmer.

I'd rather say the compiler doesn't know what *`T`* will be. It could be e.g. `Object` in which case the cast will be legal. The designers decided to prefer allowing possibly-illegal casts to disallowing possibly-legal casts in this case.

The *other* problem is that the compiler can't produce actual "cast to `T`" because JVM only has "cast to specific class" instruction. So the cast appears to succeed at runtime as well.

If you actually want to have a checked cast, you can achieve it by passing `Class<T>` as an extra argument:

```
static <T> void f1(Base arg1, Class<T> clazz) {
    T loc = clazz.cast(arg1); // will throw exception
    System.out.println(loc.getClass().getName());
}
```

In your case you *could* write

```
static <T> void f1(Base arg1, T arg2) {
    T loc = (T) arg2.getClass().cast(arg1);
    System.out.println(loc.getClass().getName());
}
```

It should be instructive to figure out in what cases it's different from the previous code.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in [JLS Sec 5.5.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1):

> Given a compile-time reference type S(source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>
> ...
>
> If T is a class type, then either |S| <: |T|, or |T| <: |S|. Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> ...
>
> If T is a type variable, then this algorithm is applied recursively, using the upper bound of T in place of T.

So the compiler is using `Object` in place of `T`, and thus it considers the cast legal.